# E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical

Tags: delphi

Ошибка в этой части кода:

```
function ExtractTokens(const line: AnsiString; const sep: AnsiChar; autoUnquote: boolean = true): TStringArray; overload; //overload;
var
  lineIndex: integer;

  function NextChar(out ch: Ansichar): boolean;
  begin
    if lineIndex <= length(line) then
    begin
      result := true;
      ch := line[lineIndex];
      inc(lineIndex);
    end
    else
      result := false;
  end;
  function PeekFor(const ch: AnsiChar): boolean;
  begin
    result := false;
    if lineIndex <= length(line) then
    begin
      if line[lineIndex] = ch then
      begin
        inc(lineIndex);
        result := true;
      end;
    end;
  end;
function UnquoteIfNecessary(const tok: string; quoteChar: char): string;
  var
    pch: PChar;
  begin
    if autoUnquote then
    begin
      pch := pchar(tok);
      result := AnsiExtractQuotedStr(pch, quoteChar);
    end
    else
      result := tok;
  end;
var
  token: string;
  stok: string;
  ch: char;
  lastChar: char;
  strSep: char;
  inString: boolean;

  function IsSep(aChar: char): boolean;
  begin
    result := (aChar = string(sep)) or ((sep = #0) and (ord(aChar) < 33));
  end;
 procedure AddToken(var tokens: TStringArray; const tkn: string; addEmpty: boolean = true);
  var
    s: string;
  begin
    s := trim(tkn);
    if addEmpty or (s <> '') then
    begin
      SetLength(tokens, length(tokens) + 1);
      tokens[high(tokens)] := s;
    end;
    token := '';
  end;
begin
  result := nil;
  token := '';
  stok := '';
  lastChar := #0;
  strSep := #0; // for compiler
  inString := false;
  lineIndex := 1;
  while true do
  begin
    if not NextChar(ch) then
    begin
      AddToken(result, token, (lastChar <> #0) and IsSep(lastChar));
      exit;
    end;

    if ch in ['"', ''''] then
    begin
      stok := stok + ch;
      if inString then
      begin
        if ch = strSep then
        begin
          if PeekFor(AnsiChar(strSep)) then
            stok := stok + strSep
          else
          begin
            token := token + UnquoteIfNecessary(stok, strSep);
            inString := false;
            stok := '';
          end;
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
        strSep := ch;
        inString := true;
      end;
    end
    else if IsSep(ch) and not inString then
      AddToken(result, token, true)
    else
    begin
      if inString then
        stok := stok + ch
      else
        token := token + ch;
    end;
    lastChar := ch;
  end;
end;
```

В этом месте:

```
if not NextChar(ch) then
```

Не пойму как это решить
В Delphi 7 все компилировалось, а в 10.2 выдает ошибку

Comment: Как объявлена функция `NextChar` и какой тип у переменной `ch`. Вам компилятор говорит, что типы аргумента и параметра не совпадают.

Comment: @zed: Самое интересное я это понимаю, а вот как решить не врубаюсь. Как я уже их не называл!

Comment: Не вижу объявления функции NextChar и переменной Ch

Comment: @ValertonGT Не видя кода, никто вам не подскажет, как его надо исправить, чтобы он заработал.

Comment: @zed: Я немного добавил кода! Банально не заметил. Библия в 40000 строк кода перевести на 10.2 - мозги немного кругом уже!

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку **и минимальный код для её воспроизведения**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в коде смешаны Ansi и юникодные строки. Вам надо все типы привести к единому, т.е. всюду использовать `string` и `char` и не использовать `AnsiString`.

Внёс буквально пару фиксов и функция скомпилировалась:

```
function ExtractTokens(const line: String; const sep: Char; autoUnquote: boolean = true): TStringArray; overload; //overload;
var
  lineIndex: integer;

  function NextChar(out ch: Char): boolean;
  begin
    if lineIndex <= length(line) then
    begin
      result := true;
      ch := line[lineIndex];
      inc(lineIndex);
    end
    else
      result := false;
  end;
  function PeekFor(const ch: Char): boolean;
  begin
    result := false;
    if lineIndex <= length(line) then
    begin
      if line[lineIndex] = ch then
      begin
        inc(lineIndex);
        result := true;
      end;
    end;
  end;
function UnquoteIfNecessary(const tok: string; quoteChar: char): string;
  var
    pch: PChar;
  begin
    if autoUnquote then
    begin
      pch := pchar(tok);
      result := AnsiExtractQuotedStr(pch, quoteChar);
    end
    else
      result := tok;
  end;
var
  token: string;
  stok: string;
  ch: char;
  lastChar: char;
  strSep: char;
  inString: boolean;

  function IsSep(aChar: char): boolean;
  begin
    result := (aChar = string(sep)) or ((sep = #0) and (ord(aChar) < 33));
  end;
 procedure AddToken(var tokens: TStringArray; const tkn: string; addEmpty: boolean = true);
  var
    s: string;
  begin
    s := trim(tkn);
    if addEmpty or (s <> '') then
    begin
      SetLength(tokens, length(tokens) + 1);
      tokens[high(tokens)] := s;
    end;
    token := '';
  end;
begin
  result := nil;
  token := '';
  stok := '';
  lastChar := #0;
  strSep := #0; // for compiler
  inString := false;
  lineIndex := 1;
  while true do
  begin
    if not NextChar(ch) then
    begin
      AddToken(result, token, (lastChar <> #0) and IsSep(lastChar));
      exit;
    end;

    if CharInSet(ch, ['"', '''']) then
    begin
      stok := stok + ch;
      if inString then
      begin
        if ch = strSep then
        begin
          if PeekFor(strSep) then
            stok := stok + strSep
          else
          begin
            token := token + UnquoteIfNecessary(stok, strSep);
            inString := false;
            stok := '';
          end;
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
        strSep := ch;
        inString := true;
      end;
    end
    else if IsSep(ch) and not inString then
      AddToken(result, token, true)
    else
    begin
      if inString then
        stok := stok + ch
      else
        token := token + ch;
    end;
    lastChar := ch;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо эта часть кода заработала! Теперь стало еще веселей: E2251 Ambiguous overloaded call to 'StrPas'